# Passing integers to another page using app.cs not working.on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-10

Hi I am trying to pass integer values to the basket on click of a button. I have successfully managed to pass strings using this method but failing to do so with numbers. When I click the button it is supposed to show the number "1" on the textbox on the basket page when I navigate from log order to basket. Instead the textbox shows 0 everytime as I set it to 0 in the design as I needed to, otherwise it would show error when running the program.

Yes I have converted the textbox to an integer and have set the textbox value to "0".

I have initialized the variable "storevalue" in app.cs.

This is my code for log order which has a button that initializes the integer to show on the textbox on the next page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace icecreamapp
{

public sealed partial class logorder : Page
{
    public logorder()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)

    {

    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App app = Application.Current as App; 

        app.storeValue = 1; //initializing variable as 1
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(basket)); //button that navigates to next page
    }
}
```

}

Code for the second page which should show display the integer in the first textbox...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;



namespace icecreamapp
{

public sealed partial class basket : Page
{
    App app = Application.Current as App;
    public basket()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        App app = Application.Current as App;
        var v = int.Parse(textBox.Text); //converting textbox to integer

        v = app.storeValue; //variable should be displayed in this textbox     and show "1"
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(logorder));
    }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: No where in your code do you set the TextBox.Text to your desired value. Are you doing some kind of Binding?

Answer (score 1):

To do this properly, you should have a service in singleton scope to capture the data for the string. You can get the service in singleton scope easily by using [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Assuming the following service is in singleton scope, you can inject it into your page or your [view model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel).

```
class CartService
{
   int storeValue {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your View or ViewModel you set the store value

```
public sealed partial class basket : Page
{
    private CartService _cartService;

    public basket(CartService cartService)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _cartService = cartService;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        App app = Application.Current as App;
        var v = int.Parse(textBox.Text); //converting textbox to integer

        v = _cartService.storeValue; //variable should be displayed in this textbox     and show "1"
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(logorder));
    }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

```
App app = Application.Current as App;
var v = int.Parse(textBox.Text); //converting textbox to integer

v = app.storeValue; //variable should be displayed in this textbox     and show "1"
```

}

What you are doing here is retrieve value from textbox and change that value to store value. Since value you are getting from textbox is not of ReferenceType it won't change when you assign new value. So do like this instead

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        App app = Application.Current as App;

    textBox.Text    = app.storeValue.ToString(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to navigate with parameter:
`Frame.Navigate(typeof(logorder), yourParameter);`
and then on page navigation check the parameter:

`protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    { var yourThing = e.Parameter; }`